# Vim snipMate tab jump

Tags: vim, snipmate

Vim snipMate doesn't work correctly

`finf[Tab]` generate

```
find(:first<+, :conditions => ['<+<+field+> = ?+>', <+true+>]+>)
```

but cursor set to end of the line and dont jump by placeholders with [Tab]

**Update:**

I try it with html - all works fine, maybe this doesn't work in *.rb files with Rails snipmates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with your snippet. I use snipMate for Python and all the placeholders looks like `${Number[:description]}`. Take a look at `~/.vim/snippets/` for examples. Belows there is a simple example for a `if` statement in ruby :

```
snippet if
    if ${1:condition}
        ${2}
```

Comment: Oh, you are rigth
vf[tab]
"validates_format_of :${1:attribute}, :with => /${2:regex}/\n"a work correct